# Matlab populate a 3 dimensional array.

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I'm quite new to Matlab and am trying to populate a 3 dimensional array. Basically I have 4 lots of `1x81` matrix that I want in one single `4x1x81` matrix. I tried to do this using a for loop to splice each `1x81` into a `4x1x81` but so far haven't had any luck. I'm sure there is a simpler way but need a fresh pair of eyes. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example and then you apply the same technique. You have to use the `colon` or `:` operator to achieve this task.

```
a=1;b=2;c=3;
```

Then a 3-D matrix can be formed as:

```
new3D_Mat(:,:,1)=a;
new3D_Mat(:,:,2)=b;
new3D_Mat(:,:,3)=c;

Output:

>> new3D_Mat

new3D_Mat(:,:,1) =

     1

new3D_Mat(:,:,2) =

     2

new3D_Mat(:,:,3) =

     3
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly did you try? How about `matrix(1,1,:)=myvector;matrix(2,1,:)=anotherone;` or a loop in which you replace the first index with the loop variable? Consider

```
>> m(1,1,:)=rand(1,3)
m =
(:,:,1) =
    0.3478
(:,:,2) =
    0.0276
(:,:,3) =
    0.5313
```

Out of curiosity, what is wrong with a 4x81 matrix? (If you already have one, `permute` may help you get a 4x1x81 3d array.)

Answer (score 0):

Why use a `4x1x81` matrix? 
Look at how easy it is to create a `4x81` matrix from four `1x81` matrices.

```
% Matrix of all ones
a = ones(1, 81);

% Matrix of all twos
b = ones(1, 81); 
b = b .*2;

% Matrix of all threes
c = ones(1, 81); c = c .*3;

% Matrix of all fours
d = ones(1, 81); d = d .*4;

% Aggregate
all_of_em = [a; b; c; d];
```

Run `whos` to see your variables.

```
Name           Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

a              1x81              648  double              
all_of_em      4x81             2592  double              
b              1x81              648  double              
c              1x81              648  double              
d              1x81              648  double
```